# How to commute two operators in python?

Tags: python, numpy, math, scipy

Let's say I have operator A and operator B which act on f(x) = 2x for example. How do I create a function that says whether A(B(f(x))) == B(A(f(x))) in python?

Here is my attempt:

```
#Commutation: Creating a function that checks whether operators A and B commutate on some dummy function f(x) = 2*x
#[A,B](2x) =?= 0

def commutate(A,B):
    f = lambda x: 2*x
    if lambda x: A(B(f)) - B(A(f)) == 0:
        print('A and B commute!')
    else:
        print('A and B do not commute!')
         
A = lambda x: f(x)**2

B = lambda x: np.log(f(x))


commutate(A,B)
```

The issue is that I'm always getting that the operators A and B commute, even when giving Operators that don't. I suspect this might have to do with the fact that I can't Define operators like that in python?

Comment: You're just checking to see if a `lambda` expression is truthy, so the answer is always yes.  The thing that I think you're trying to do (subtract a function from another) doesn't work; if your order of operations was correct for what you're trying to do, you'd see ` TypeError` telling you that you can't subtract functions from each other.

Comment: Numerically you could check if `A(B(x))` and `B(A(x))` produce the same result for different `x` values. But this way you can only prove that they are different, for equality you will need actual algebra.

Answer (score 3):

In general, it is not possible, based on [Rice theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem). Because you desire to check a non-trivial property for two pieces of code, i.e., the property is commutativeness and piece of code here means functions. Hence, it proves that deciding that "any given `f` and `g` functions are commutative" is **undecidable**. Therefore, you can't write such a function to check the commutativeness for two functions.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have the line

```
if lambda x: A(B(f)) - B(A(f)) == 0:
```

In this line you are generating a lambda that is calling the operators on the address of `f` rather than a result of calling `f`. Also, you are not calling the lambda that you define in the if statement, so you are checking if the address of the lambda function is True/False which is not what you are looking for.

Lambdas are just functions, but you could test if the operators are commutative on a specific value:

```
def commutate(A, B, value):
    f = lambda x: 2 * x
    if A(B(f(value))) == B(A(f(value))):
        print(f"A and B commute on value {value}!")
    else:
        print(f"A and B do not commute on value {value}!")
```